# Maven WildFly Deployment Failure with Conflicting JNDI Bindings and Missing Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jpa, deployment, wildfly

I have created a Maven project in Eclipse and created a JPA project here. I have also created the Run Confiuration. When I run the POM.xml I get the following error message and the Build Fails:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hiring-process</groupId>
    <artifactId>edu.thi.hipro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>edu.thi.hipro</name>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <finalName>edu.thi.hipro</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error Code:

```
[INFO] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] Total time:  6.577 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-29T15:16:29+01:00
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [32morg.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:4.2.0.Final:deploy[m [1m(default-cli)[m on project [36mjpa-ejb-services[m: [1;31mFailed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jpa-ejb-services.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"jpa-ejb-services.war\"[m
[ERROR] [1;31m    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYEE0047: Incompatible conflicting binding at java:jboss/exported/jpa-ejb-services/CustomerServiceBean!edu.thi.services.ejb.CustomerServiceBeanRemote source: org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor$2@598cbd4b"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"jpa-ejb-services.war\".beanmanager","jboss.deployment.unit.\"jpa-ejb-services.war\".WeldStartService"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"jpa-ejb-services.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"jpa-ejb-services.war\".beanmanager]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"jpa-ejb-services.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"jpa-ejb-services.war\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\"jpa-ejb-services.war\".WeldStartService]"]}}}[m
[ERROR] -> [1m[Help 1][m
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I hope the problem can be solved as I don't know what to do and this is needed for a student project

Comment: Is there an error in the server logs? You might get more information there.